# Sass nesting, mark for the first parent element

Tags: css, sass

I have a root element `div.container` at my page, there is `div.block.scarlet` inside with **red color** for text.
But we also have `body` is a parent for `div.container element`. And when `body` has class `.landing` I need to make **pink color** instead of red.
I don't understand how write it correctly. Help with a syntax please!

```
/* how I do it now */
.container {
    .block {
        &.scarlet {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
body.landing .container {
    .block {
        &.scarlet {
            color: pink;
        }
    }
}
```

Tooooo much extra copy-paste code! Is it possible to write in one line? Maybe a trick or smth like sass `&`. What I want:

```
.container {
    .block {
        &.scarlet {
            color: red;
            @if(body.landing || container.landing) { color: pink }
        }
    }
}
```

This is short rule that recolor my text if the root nesting element changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [parent selector reference](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector) to construct complete selector from current context:

```
.container {
    .block {
        &.scarlet {
            color: red;
            body.landing & { 
                color: pink; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```